# Remove triple dots when rendering Quarto as html and revealjs

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

When writing a quarto document to be exported as revealjs, triple dots ". . ." are used to define fragments. However, when rendering also as html, the triple dots are not parsed, and they appear on the document. MWE

```
---
format:
  html: 
     output-file: website.html
  revealjs: 
     output-file: slides.html
---

Hi, 

. . .

friends
```

The expect behaviour is that the . . . should not appear in website.html

Is there a way remove them?

**Edit**: I would like to avoid adding code to the body of the text.

Maybe this feature does not exist, and I can make a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it can be done with lua as indicated by this reply
https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2302#issuecomment-1237212189

(although it seems to say "or" when they want to say "and")

creating a `remove-pause.lua` file

```
Para = function(e)
  if (not quarto.doc.isFormat("revealjs") and not quarto.doc.isFormat("beamer") and not quarto.doc.isFormat("pptx")) then
    if (e == pandoc.Para '. . .') then
      return {}
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

and adding to the header

```
filters: 
  - remove-pause.lua
```